# Spaces with Messaging.SingleEmailMessage setHTMLBody method

Tags: html, singleemailmessage

I'm using the Apex class `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage.setHTMLBody()` to send an email from Salesforce with prettier than ASCII formatting.  For the life of me I can't figure out how to insert an extra white space.  It's usually &nbsp but the Apex prints that exact string out instead of substituting a white space.  Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `&nbsp;`

The following anonymous apex worked for me with my Exchange email client receiving the email:

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
mail.setToAddresses(new String[] {'foo@bar.com'});
mail.setSubject('stackforce answer');
String messageBody = '<html><body>Hi, welcome to &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Our World</body>  </html>';
mail.setHtmlBody(messageBody); 
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
```

generating this email (as received by Outlook 2010):

```
Hi, welcome to    Our World
```

Comment: You "ate" `&` in `&nbsp;` ;)

Comment: fixed answer, tx

Comment: You're right it's `&nbsp`.  What I hadn't done was to put `<html>` tags into the email.  Everything else worked without it so I assumed `.setHtmlBody()` had done that for me.  Apparently not...

Answer (score 0):

Mention &nbsp in single quotes as follows

```
String messageBody = '<html><body>Hi, welcome to + '&nbsp'+Our World</body></html>';
```